# Cannot make an "Errors" Object in a React Login Form Component's state function properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, material-ui

The problem arised when I was following this React [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0&list=WL&index=31&t=19321s).

The goal is to create a simple social media web app with Firebase, React, MaterialUI, etc.

I am around the 5:40:00 mark and I've managed to debug every problem I've encountered up until this point, but right now I've been stuck for more than an hour on something that seems like a stupid mistake. The segment that I'm on is creating the login page. I've successfully created the login form and it functions (meaning that it will redirect the user to the home page if the right user credentials are submitted). What doesn't function thought is the helperText of the input fields. The way it's supposed to work is to display an error and give Helper text with the value of an error object, which is generated by this basic LoginValidaton function in the back-end:

```
exports.validateLoginData = (userData) => {
  let errors = {};

  if (isEmpty(userData.email)) {
    errors.email = "Must not be empty";
  }
  if (isEmpty(userData.password)) {
    errors.password = "Must not be empty";
  }

  return {
    errors,
    valid: Object.entries(errors).length === 0 ? true : false,
  };
};
```

Which yields the following response when called through Postman: [linkForPicture](https://i.gyazo.com/7fda7a235b38be36eadd4b7a6b55a1a2.png)

And should look like this: [linkForPicture](https://i.gyazo.com/06c63ca28d9d22018fee82efd7b1d045.png)

However, in reality, it gives a bad request error in the console and logs the errors object. [linkForPicture](https://i.gyazo.com/84ce3a27a32f8efc026743f9eb5f8448.png)

Here is the code for my Login Page without the imports and styling parts:

```
class login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      loading: false,
      errors: {},
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };
    axios
      .post("/login", userData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.props.history.push("/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({
          errors: err.response.data,
          loading: false,
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { errors, loading } = this.state;

    console.log(errors);

    return (
      <Grid container className={classes.form}>
        <Grid item sm />
        <Grid item sm>
          <img className={classes.logo} src={AppLogo} alt="no-nudes"></img>
          <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.pageTitle}>
            Login
          </Typography>
          <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              id="email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              label="E-mail"
              className={classes.textField}
              helperText={errors.email}
              error={errors.email ? true : false}
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              id="password"
              name="password"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              className={classes.textField}
              helperText={errors.password}
              error={errors.password ? true : false}
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              fullWidth
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Sign-in
            </Button>
          </form>
          <Typography>{errors.email}</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Although I am not sure, I believe the current code creates an object 'errors' in the state with the following properties when the form is submitted with empty text fields

```
errors: {
    "errors": {
        "email": "Must not be empty",
        "password": "Must not be empty"
    }
}
```

and so I tried to access it in the helperText with something like {errors.errors.email}, but this results in the following error: [linkForPicture](https://i.gyazo.com/014e8374009fa72634fa0e6b876c3094.png)

I would be extremely grateful if I received some sort of guidance to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is both with your `.catch() { ...setState()` and what your API is returning.

You're setting a new object that looks like this:

```js
{
  errors: err.response.data,
  loading: false
}
```

but what's inside your `err.response.data` ie what's being returned by your API?

```js
{
  errors: {
    email: "Must not be empty",
    password": "Must not be empty",
  }
}
```

ANOTHER object that already has errors as the property name.

That's why your state ends up with:

```js
{
  errors: {
    errors: {
      email: "Must not be empty",
      password": "Must not be empty",
    }
  },
  loading: false
}
```

you can either get your API to return just the error object:

```js
{
  email: "Must not be empty",
  password: "Must not be empty",
}
```

or in your `setState()`, set the content of the new piece of state to the `errors` property your API is returning:

```js
  .catch((err) => {
    this.setState({
      errors: err.response.data.errors, //here
      loading: false,
    });
```

**Update: Why is `helperText={errors.errors.email}` giving undefined?**
Have a look at how you initialised your `state` object in your constructor function. Your `errors` property is an empty object `{}`.

So in the initial render, *before you've clicked submit*, your `helperText` prop in your `<TextField>` is trying to access an undefined property in your initially declared `error` object. There's nothing there atm! You only get something there after you click the Submit button.

If you want it to not show undefined, you could always fill it with an empty string:

```js
this.state = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
  loading: false,
  errors: {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  },
};
```

Having said that, this is probably not a very good way to manage error messages. Look into form validation for React. There's alotta libraries out there!